# Extends a class(which implements interface) and implements same interface doesn't require method defination in class?

Tags: java, class, interface

/*Class C has implemented interface A but has not defined go() method is it correct ?*/

```
interface A { void go();}
Class B implements A { void go(){#Some code here}}
Class C extends B implements C {}
```

Comment: Can we assume that `Class C` should have `implements A`?

Comment: class C extends B implements `C{}` where is `C interface`

Comment: I am getting this in eclipse "Cycle detected: the type C cannot extend/implement itself or one of its own member types"

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. However, a method in an interface is `public abstract` even though you don't define it like that.

The implementing class method must be public as well, because you cannot reduce method visibility. So, the method in class `B` should be `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a C is a B and therefore has the method definition from B. If you really want this to work, you must create an Abstract Base Class for both B and C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C extends B which has implemented `go`, therefore C inherits this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. Since it has already *inherited* the method from `B`. In fact, the `implements A` for class `C` is redundant!